# Magento Installation permission issue

Tags: install, magento-community, permissions, access

I have try to install magento CE Version 1.9.0.1.But when i am trying   to install magento  from browser.it show permission issue :

```
Path "/var/www/html/magento/app/etc" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/downloadable" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/system" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/system/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/custom" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/custom/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/original" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/original/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/dhl" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/dhl/logo.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/customer" must be writable.
```

I am using `Fedora` my Os System and was give permission 777 to /`var/www/html`

using `chmod 777 -R /var/www/html` and show same issue.
**Can anyone help me ??**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are issue in Linux kernel security module (Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux)) i.e SELinux  permission issue.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux

I have doing this by

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/magento/
chmod -R a+w /var/www/html/magento/
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do chmod -R 777 /var/www/html since that will make your whole site writeable.**

See [Magento Writeable Permissions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions)

Try Setting your folders, app and media to

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento/media
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento/var
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento/app/etc
```

Comment: dude it not working.my  magento folder user is amit

Comment: Are you uploading with filezilla? or do you have direct access via ssh or something? If you have direct access try going into the magento folder and running chown -R 777 /media

Comment: i doning allthing on local system .local ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: You would still need to adjust the write permissions for the folders. Do you have a GUI or are you in a terminal shell?

Comment: doing all thing from terminal

Comment: chown tries to change file owner to 777. I don't think you want to try out THAT command.

Comment: Ah, True. Sorry about that. Edited.

Comment: 777 is insecure!

Comment: @black please provide a better file permission because 755 and 644 do not work.

Comment: @ZacGrierson, use 775 and 664

Answer (score 1):

I'm shooting from the hip here, but shouldn't you do:

> chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

instead of

> chmod 777 -R /var/www/html

as options should come BEFORE mode?

Comment: not working ??? dude

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you using? You might need to be root in order to update permissions. Try sudo before the command you are using. 
Also, 777 is way to permissive for any installation, specially if its live in an accessible server.

Comment: i have already said  ,i am using fedora....seeing   that user for folder is apache at  /var/www/html/magento

Comment: Try sudo before your command. Can you past the entire output of the chmod with and without sudo?